# Failed build while collecting changes from other repository

Tags: svn, msbuild, teamcity, svn-checkout

Getting the following error while trying to do checkout

Build errors
#

```
[11:27:20]Failed to start build
[11:27:20]Failed to collect changes, error: Error collecting changes for VCS repository 'ibtis' org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: Externals problem: processExternalsChanges, externals URL: http://server1/svn/ibtis/trunk/UserControls, version: -1, path:UserControls, original error: svn: E175002: unknown host svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/ibtis/trunk/UserControls' svn: E175002: unknown host svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/ibtis/trunk/UserControls'
```

In teamcity current svn url is URL: http://server2/svn/ibtis/trunk and basically it copies changes from other http://server1/svn/ibtis/trunk.

Any idea whats going wrong here. What setting I am giving wrong or is it not possible to do it from teamcity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my scenario, the problem was with shared externals folders path on svn. They are using hard coded path so If you try to copy from one repository to another it fails to copy. In order to fix this change the shared folder externals path to relative path e.g So you would likely need to use ^/../OtherRepo/trunk/CommonLibrary instead of a hard coded path.

Answer (score 8):

I was having similar issues when trying to connect to an SVN repository up on beanstalk and was getting this error:

> svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed

After much searching I found [this post](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5452543) which fixed the problem for me.

Essentially, you need to modify your Java Options of your TeamCity tomcat service because the SVN fails to authenticate via SSL.  I notice that the svn url you are using is "http://" - are you sure this is correct?

(Assuming Windows OS)

1. Open a command prompt and go to \teamcity\bin\
2. type 'tomcat7w.exe
   //ES//TeamCity'  - which will bring up 'TeamCity Web Server
   Properties' dialog (assuming the name of your TeamCity webservice is
   'TeamCity')
3. Click on the 'Java' tab and type '-Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols=SSLv3' into the Java Options textbox (after everything else)
4. Restart the service
5. Awesomeness

Comment: I had the same problem... but the problem dissapeared after I upgrade to TeamCity 7.1.1